# How to call a new activity without calling a new "window"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

I am trying to call a new activity using an intent, but every time I call it, I can see a new "window" open on my android device. Can I call a new activity that will be in the same window? What I mean is calling new activity without visually seeing that it has been opened.
Hope you understand my question :) Thank you!

Comment: Please add some code that shows what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `Fragments`

Start reading [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Fragments actually use the "same" window (Activity) and just replaces layouts and views - I think exactly like you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run something like a unix-demon code(this mean a program that is only executed in the background without no visual components) you are looking for a android Service.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Otherwise if you are looking for a visual component that don't create new windows but refresh the old one, you could use the Fragment class if your android version is 3.0 or higher.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

In an Activity content view, create an empty relativeLayout.

As mentioned in previous answers, create fragments and replace this relativeLayout with  the newly created fragment using FragmentManager.

FOr reference use [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Its really easy. try this.